# Uploading image using RobotFramework in hidden input element

Tags: selenium, firefox, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

Due to **hidden="hidden"** I cannot run automated test with Robot Framework.

Kindly suggest me some idea to resolve it.

HTML code:

```
<a _ngcontent-c8="" class="browse cursor-pointer" tabindex="0">Browse</a>        
<input _ngcontent-c8="" id="file" style="border: 1px solid gray; cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; width: 300px;" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff" type="file" hidden="hidden">
```

Comment: Hi @AshishKamble . this is our html code -  <input _ngcontent-c8="" id="file" style="border: 1px solid gray; cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; width: 300px;" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff" type="file" hidden="hidden"> –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround for that - make the element visible through javascript, just before interacting with it:

```
Execute Javascript    document.getElementById('file'‌​).style.visibility='‌​visible'
```

UPDATE:

If you want to set an attribute different from `style`, like in this case a custom one called `hidden`, you use a different js method:

```
Execute Javascript    document.getElementById('file'‌​).setAttribute('hidden') = 'new_value'
```

, where "new_value" is the one you know will make it visible.

And if you want to remove it altogether, the call is

```
Execute Javascript    document.getElementById('file'‌​).removeAttribute('hidden')
```

Comment: still not getting visible <input _ngcontent-c8="" id="file" style="border: 1px solid gray; cursor: pointer; margin: 5px; width: 300px; visibility: visible;" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .tif, .tiff" type="file" hidden="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still struggling with the SyntaxErrors like me, here is the correct syntax for setAttribute that works for me:

```
Execute Javascript document.getElementById('file'‌​).setAttribute('attributeName', 'attributeValue');
```

And if you don't have the id attribute:

```
Execute Javascript document.getElementsByClassName('file'‌​)[0].setAttribute('attributeName', 'attributeValue');
```

FYI:The method getElementsByClassName return an array of elements.